# Regex to remove .csv in r

Tags: regex, r, stringr

this is going to be silly.

I have a string like:

```
word <- "dirtyboards.csv"
```

I want to remove the csv part and get "dirtyboards".

I am trying:

```
require(stringr)
str_extract(word, ".*[^.csv]")
```

I get in return: "dirtyboard" . The "s" before the ".csv" goes missing.

I know I can do ,

`gsub(".csv", "", word)`

Comment: `sub(".csv$","",word)`

Comment: Try `str_extract(word, '.*(?=\\.csv)')`  You are not getting `s` because the character inside `[^.csv]` is not matched.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(word, '.*(?=\\.csv)')
#[1] "dirtyboards"
```

Another option which works for the example provided (and not very specific)

```
str_extract(word, '^[^.]+')
#[1] "dirtyboards"
```

#### Update

Including 'foo.csv.csv',

```
word1 <- c("dirtyboards.csv" , "boardcsv.csv", "foo.csv.csv")
str_extract(word1, '.*(?=\\.csv$)')
#[1] "dirtyboards" "boardcsv"    "foo.csv"
```

Comment: What about `foo.csv.csv` ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj That should be a rare case.

Answer (score 9):

Base R has an ap for that:

```
word <- "dirtyboards.csv" 
tools::file_path_sans_ext(word)

## [1] "dirtyboards"
```

Comment: I love that they're adding functions like this, but good grief they aren't helping the R naming conventions issue at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
word <- c("dirtyboards.csv","boardcsv.csv")
sub(".csv$","",word)
[1] "dirtyboards" "boardcsv"
```

Comment: The OP mentioned in the post that he/she know about the `gsub` route.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check it.

Comment: why does OP even ask the question in the first place?

Comment: @akrun: Not a problem. plafort: OP might have a good reason for that.

Answer (score 1):

If your situation is like it is presented, you can try:

```
substr(word, 1, nchar(word)-4)
[1] "dirtyboards"
```

This code starts from the first character and captures the rest of the string up to the last four tokens. The solution wholly depends on the application involved.

Comment: OP's example is specific to `.csv`.  Having said that, if there are files like `.xlsx`, this would also fail

Comment: I agree. My response does read a bit snarky @akrun. The application is the most important aspect.

Comment: I just pointed out one case where it fails.  I like TylerRinker's as well.  Anyway, I did gave you +1.  As AvinashRaj mentioned, there are rare cases where my initial code failed too.